# Measure average time per action in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, time, measure

In Excel VBA I am trying to measure elapsed time per one cycle of For - Next loop, but without success.
My code is as follows:

```
time_beginning= Now

For i = start_row To end_row
number_cycles= i - start_row
time_now= Now
elapsed_time= time_now- time_beginning
time_per_cycle= Int(elapsed_time* 24 * 60 * 60 / number_cycles)
Application.StatusBar = "Time per cycle " & CStr(time_per_cycle)
... do some tasks
Next i
```

I am getting error:

> "Run-time error '6': Overflow"

for the line

```
time_per_cycle= Int(elapsed_time* 24 * 60 * 60 / number_cycles)
```

Can you help?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you getting an error? [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/8422953)

Comment: edited the post with the error description

Comment: "number_cycles" defaults to 0, Dividing by zero is a bad idea.

Comment: number_cycles is always > 0

Comment: So print the total number of cycles... then you will be sure.

Comment: If `i = start_row` and `number_cycles = i - start_row` how can it not be 0? If **start_row = 5**, then **number_cycles = 5 -5**  Try `number_cycles= i - start_row +1`

Comment: Chirstofer Weber was right. It was diving by zero. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As I said, dividing by zero is a bad idea, and trying your code, number_cycles did indeed end up being **0**.
I couldn't get your timer to work properly anyway, so I just used another approach. The worksheet function `Now()` instead of the vba one, to get fractions of a second.
Then I print the time after the loop instead of before, otherwise the first print will always be 0.

```
Dim start_row As Long, end_row As Long, i As Long, number_cycles As Long
Dim time_start As Date

time_beginning = [now()]

For i = start_row To end_row
    number_cycles = i - start_row + 1

    ... do some tasks

    Debug.Print ("Time per cycle " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Text(([now()] - time_beginning) / number_cycles, "mm:ss.000"))
Next i
End Sub
```